# If div children don't have same text content then do action

Tags: javascript, json, for-loop, if-statement, dom

I'm trying to create DOM elements for an Ingredient filter bar, based on JSON file objects.

The problem is that the same ingredient can appear in several objects, and in that case it should only create the dom element once, not for each time the ingredient occures.

I've tried with `childNode`, `value`, `innerHTML`  and `!===` but can't figure out the solution. It either creates no element at all, or all of them with duplicates.

Any ideas?

Here is a codePen to help : https://codepen.io/enukeron/pen/eYdgyzx

I also tried with an array to keep track of seen values at this codepen :
https://codepen.io/enukeron/pen/ExgZoLa

JS:

```
const ingredientDropdown = document.getElementById('ingredientDropdown');

for(var j = 0; j < IngredientList.length; j++) {
   if (ingredientDropdown.children.textContent !== IngredientList[j].ingredient) {
      var ingredientSearchItems = document.createElement("p");
      ingredientSearchItems.textContent = IngredientList[j].ingredient;
      ingredientDropdown.appendChild(ingredientSearchItems);
   }
}
```

The JSON file has this format :

```
    {
        "id": 49,
        "name": "Tropical smoothie",
        "servings": 4,
        "ingredients": [
            {
                "ingredient": "Bananas",
                "quantity": 2
            },
            {
                "ingredient": "Kiwis",
                "quantity": 3
            },
            {
                "ingredient": "Mango",
                "quantity": 1
            },
            {
                "ingredient": "Pineapple",
                "quantity": 4,
                "unit":"slices"
            },
            {
                "ingredient": "Honey",
                "quantity": 2,
                "unit": "tablespoons"
            }
        ],
        "time": 0,
        "description":"Chop the fruit. Liquefy in the blender. Chill. Serve",
        "appliance": "Blender",
        "ustensils":["couteau", "verres"]
    }, etc.....
```

The actual result is : [image]

The Expected Result is : [image]

Comment: Please click edit, the `[<>]` snippet editor and create a [mcve]

Comment: Hint: Use an Array, Set or Object to keep track of the values you have already seen

Comment: this question itself lacks many ingredients of understanding ...

Comment: I just added a minimalist CodePen

Comment: @charlietfl I tried that out (https://codepen.io/enukeron/pen/ExgZoLa) but didn't seem to work neither

Comment: You are creating a new `Seen` array every iteration of the loop. Define it outside the outer loop so it is cumulative for all objects in main array

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks a Lot !  If you want to put that as Answer I'll accept it ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a function like the following:

```
function filterIngredients(recipes){
  let return_arr = [];
  recipes.forEach((recipe, index, array)=>{
    let ingredients = recipe["ingredients"];
    ingredients.forEach((ingredient, index, inner_array)=>{
      if(!return_arr.includes(ingredient["ingredient"])){
        return_arr.push(ingredient["ingredient"]);
      }
    });
  });
  return return_arr;
}
```

And then call the function as follows:

```
var ingredients = filterIngredients(recipes);
```

You can then loop through `ingredients` and display them in the div as you want (hoping this is what you wanted in the first place).
Here is a link to my pen where I implemented it:
https://codepen.io/AnirudhMS/pen/MWjJQgg?editors=1010

Comment: That's what I ended up doing on @charlietfl's advice, thanks a lot :)